# Getting an error in h2o.Ensemble

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

I am trying to run stacked ensemble in h2o using h2o.Ensemble and getting this error .

> Error in h2o.randomForest(x = x, y = y, training_frame = training_frame,  : 
>     unused argument (offset_column = offset_column)

Comment: Please check this and then update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a temporary [bug](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5335) in H2O where the `offset_column` and `distribution` were removed from the Random Forest in H2O 3.18.0.1 and 3.18.0.2.  The **h2oEnsemble** wrapper functions are expecting those parameters to be there, which is why you see the error.

This has been fixed already in the nightly releases, so it should work if you download and install the latest nightly release of H2O [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html).